# moment - Find name of the day in a given month

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm able to get name of the day using moment + format options.

```
moment().format('dddd');
```

However it only returns name of day for current month.

How can I specify a specific month? say name of day for June 30 2017.

Thanks

Comment: `moment()` creates a Moment object for the current day/time. If you want to specify a certain other day, pass an appropriate parameter to `moment()` according to the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/), or use a setter function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
moment().format('dddd MMMM Do YYYY'); // name-of-day June 30 2017
```

Hopefully that will help you!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the day name in the host default language if the host supports options to [*toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) (which is all current browsers, but you'll need a fallback for older hosts):

```js
var d = new Date(2017,5,30); // 30 Jun 2017
console.log(d.toLocaleString(undefined,{weekday:'long'}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 moment().format('June 30 2017','dddd MMMM YYYY').day();
```

https://github.com/moment/momentjs.com/blob/master/docs/moment/02-get-set/06-day.md

Answer (score 0):

You may pass the information to moment, and get name of day for that day/month like this:

```
moment('June 30 2017').format('dddd')
```